# How to change image on button?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have two bottom left (<) side button and right (>) button. I have to change the images from array with left and right button action?

Code :

```
- (IBAction)onClickRightLeft:(id)sender {

    switch ([sender tag]) {
        case 10:
            indexValueL++;
            if(indexValueL >= 3)
            {
                indexValueL = 2;
            }
            if(indexValueL < 0)
            {
                indexValueL=0;
            }
            [imgViewStory setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[[[arrGlobal objectAtIndex:indexValueL] valueForKey:@"FeaturedStoryImage"]]]];
            break;
        case 20:
            indexValueR++;
            if(indexValueR >= 3)
            {
                indexValueR = 2;
            }
            if(indexValueR < 0)
            {
                indexValueR=0;
            }
            [imgViewStory setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[[[arrGlobal objectAtIndex:indexValueR] valueForKey:@"FeaturedStoryImage"]]]];
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
```

How do I manage an array index?

Comment: show us what you have tried so far...

Comment: don't use `indexValueL` & `indexValueR`. Just use **one** `indexValue` & try again...

Comment: thx,but where to minus array index ??

Comment: on left click it will be - & on right click it will be +.

Comment: does my answer solves your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should do.. (not tested)

```
- (IBAction)onClickRightLeft:(id)sender {

    switch ([sender tag]) {
        case 10: // considering right clicked
            indexValue++;
            break;
        case 20: // considering left clicked
            indexValue--;
            break;
    }

    if(indexValue >= 3)
    {
        indexValue = 0;
    }
    if(indexValue < 0)
    {
        indexValue=2;
    }
    [imgViewStory setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[[[arrGlobal objectAtIndex:indexValue] valueForKey:@"FeaturedStoryImage"]]]];
```

Also while showing image, you should consider it caching & asynch loading. Check [this for more info](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage)